# Dealing with hidden elements

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website and the problem is, I cannot interact with hidden elements present on the website. The code is as follows:

**Before clicking**

```
li class="header-nav__item login header-item-is-hidden" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display:list-item"

<a class="header-nav__link" href="#login-panel" aria-controls="login-panel" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true"></a>

<script src="../../../Scripts/Login/Login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/Login/2FALogin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/common/error-handing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="Login_pnlDownTime"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
li
```

**After clicking**

```
li class="header-nav__item jp-login header-item-is-hidden is-active" data-toggle="dropdown" style="display:list-item"

<a class="header-nav__link" href="#login-panel" aria-controls="login-panel" aria-expanded="true" aria-haspopup="true"></a>

<script src="../../../Scripts/Login/Login.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/Login/2FALogin.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../../Scripts/common/error-handing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="Login_pnlDownTime"></div>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>

li
```

**My source code**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.website.com/Home.aspx")
print driver.page_source
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul[@class = 'header-nav']/li[3]") 
#this is deon because the list element here is the third element in the list
ele.click()
```

Here on clicking the element, the dropdown does not become visible. Also, `ele.click()` is emulating the behaviour of hovering on the element, and not clicking the element.

**Source code of the element that'll drop down on the click**

```
div id="Login_pnlDownTime" /div
div id="login-panel" class="js-header-panel header-nav__dropdown right" aria-hidden="true" /div
::before
a class="privilege-promo form-section" href="/EN/enrol-now.aspx">/a
div class="privilege-form form-section"
fieldset class="frm frm--vertical"
input id="Login_hddnInvalidEmail" type="hidden" value="Invalid Email Id" name="ctl00$Login$hddnInvalidEmail"> /input
input id="Login_hddnInvalidNumber" type="hidden" value="Invalid Number" name="ctl00$Login$hddnInvalidNumber"> /input
input id="Login_hddnInvalidMobileNumber" type="hidden" value="Invalid Mobile Number" name="ctl00$Login$hddnInvalidMobileNumber"> /input
input id="Login_hddnFlashMessageDelay" type="hidden" value="10000" name="ctl00$Login$hddnFlashMessageDelay"> /input
button id="Login_btnSubmitLogin" class="btn btn-primary align-right" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBac…n$btnSubmitLogin", "", true, "LoginPage", "", false, false))" value="Continue" name="ctl00$Login$btnSubmitLogin" type="submit"> /button
```

How to perform the click on the element?

Comment: @Parkhar, could you share the link to the source page?

Comment: What if you make them visible, click and hide again?

Comment: @IgorSavinkin I'll just put i some more source code since I cannot post the link of the website. Tell me, what do you need?

Comment: @StasBerkov So basically the element is clicked on, the dropdown becomes visible and then goes away immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing element is not (becomes) visible (css: *display:none*) and the other thing the element is removed from DOM ex. *[removeChild()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_removechild.asp)* method by Javascript.

- In the first case it's still in DOM though hidden, so Selenium webdriver should be able to find it by *id* or other attribute.
- In the second case you can't do much (it's not in DOM).

From your *before/after clicking html* it's not clear where is the element/what happens with it. Would you use developer tools to inspect it in real time and post screenshots/html in your question?

### Update

I found NO elements with `class='header-nav'` only `header-nav__dropdown` which is not `header-nav`. You should be aware of it!
If you want to locate with class starting with `header-nav` then use `starts-with()` function.

Second, the element is `div`, not `ul` according to your xpath. So `div id="login-panel" class="js-header-panel header-nav__dropdown right" aria-hidden="true" /div` can't be located and clicked.

Could you paste in your question the real html with `ul` and `li`s, class='header-nav' etc. ?

> I cannot interact with it since it says that the element isn't visible

Seems to me you have not mastered the web dev tools in browser. You must be able to see all unvisible elements in dev. tools inspector. See [this](https://webscraping.pro/python-lxml-scrape-online-dictionary/) and [this](https://webscraping.pro/scraper-google-chrome-extension-review/) posts how I do that.

Comment: Check the edit. I've added the source code of the drop down, if this doesn't help, I'll add the screenshots too.

Also, I can find the DOM element but I cannot interact with it since it says that the element isn't visible. The drop down contains a form that I have to fill, and I cannot do that since it is not visible.